# Automating conversion of multiple PowerPoint presentations to wmv in Office 2010

Tags: conversion, microsoft-powerpoint, wmv

I have scripted changes to PowerPoint presentations and generate 45-60 different versions with minor slide changes at time.

This all happens from an excel list For Each date listed.

The next step in the loop is to convert them to wmv and I can get there with:

```
ActivePresentation.Convert2 FileName:=pptPath & strTitle & ".wmv"
```

which works fine for the first 4 versions and then I get this debug error
[image: error image]

Although the conversion of the previous 4 files continues correctly and they complete fine.

I assume there must be a resource or queue issue I am not sure how to handle that.
Googling the error, I haven't found mhat seemed to match

Anyone that can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the issue was that my scripting was trying to convert two PowerPoint presentations into a wmv with the same name. So it was an error on my part, resolved by creating unique naming for the wmvs.

Comment: not sure whether it is appropriate to check my own answer, but it is the reason